# d[7:0] is an input vector, which shows to be ZZ in the simulation waveform. When does such a situation arise in a Xilinx Vivado simulation?

Tags: verilog, xilinx, vivado

d[7:0] is an input vector, which shows to be ZZ in the simulation waveform. When does such a situation arise in a Xilinx Vivado simulation ? What mistake I might have made which is resulting in this error ?

Answer (score 2):

You have never assigned any value to the signal. Check your connections. Also check all your signal names. (Capitalization typos etc.)